# Question on O.D.E

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given  three parameters $L,a$ and $\alpha$, we consider the
 differential equation : $$(E)\qquad x''+\alpha x' +a x + \sin x =L, \ 
 t\geq0$$ 
Assume that $a>0$ and $\alpha\geq 0$

We consider the fonctionnelle $V(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{ax^2}{2}-Lx-\cos x$

where $y=x'$, and we have that there existe $C>0$ such that :$\displaystyle\frac{a x^2}{4} +\frac{y^2}{2}\leq C+1+\frac{L^2}{a}$ .

I want to prove that:

Deduce that if  $a>0$ and $\alpha >0$,  then there exists a constant $M=M(\alpha,a,L)$ (regardless of baseline values​​) such that

> $$\forall (x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2,\ \exists T_0 ,\text{such that}\forall t\geq T_0,\  x^2(t)+y^2(t)\leq M.$$

I was asked to follow these steps but i don't know how to prove it :

> 1)Show that $V$ tends to a limit as $ t \to +\infty$ and
>   $\dfrac{d^2V}{dt^2}$ is bounded.
>
> 2)Deduce that $\dfrac{d V}{dt}$ tends to $0$ and $y$ tends to $0$.
>
> 3)Show that $\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ is bounded. Deduce that
>   $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ tends to $0$.
>
> 4)Show that $x +\sin x $ tends to $L$ and conclude that $M
>  =\left(\dfrac{|L|+1}{a} \right)^2+1$ is appropriated.

Can someone help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: For 1) first compute $dV/dt$ you will see that $dV/dt \leq 0$. So to prove that it has a limit you just need to show that $V(t)$ is bounded from below. Specifically you need to suitably underbound $-Lx$. To do this use the given inequality (Note that the inequality gives an an upper- and underbound on $x$ since there is a square)

Comment: In 2) do you mean $dV/dt$ and $y$ go to zero as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: In the first equation block the inequality sign after "such that" does not make any sense

Comment: hi @Novo ,i found$V(x,y)\geq \frac{ax^2}{2}-Lx-1\geq-\frac{L^2}{2a}-1 $ it is true ?